# Is the Proteus viable as a mission runner?

Tags: eve-online

I don't want a Tengu, spare me the comment please.

I want to know if a Proteus can stand on it's own when it comes to missions. Especially when I have to deal with a lot of webbers and dampeners, which I have a lot because of Serpentis.

I came up with this fitting so far:

```
[Proteus, New Setup 1]
Medium Armor Repairer II
Armor Kinetic Hardener II
Armor Thermic Hardener II
Armor Thermic Hardener II
Magnetic Field Stabilizer II
Magnetic Field Stabilizer II
Energized Adaptive Nano Membrane II

Cap Recharger II
Cap Recharger II
10MN Afterburner II

250mm Railgun II, Caldari Navy Antimatter Charge M
250mm Railgun II, Caldari Navy Antimatter Charge M
250mm Railgun II, Caldari Navy Antimatter Charge M
250mm Railgun II, Caldari Navy Antimatter Charge M
250mm Railgun II, Caldari Navy Antimatter Charge M
250mm Railgun II, Caldari Navy Antimatter Charge M

Medium Capacitor Control Circuit I
Medium Capacitor Control Circuit I
Medium Hybrid Collision Accelerator I

Proteus Defensive - Nanobot Injector
Proteus Electronics - CPU Efficiency Gate
Proteus Engineering - Power Core Multiplier
Proteus Offensive - Hybrid Propulsion Armature
Proteus Propulsion - Localized Injectors


Hammerhead II x5
Hobgoblin II x5
```

Can a Proteus with such a fitting hold on it's own in most Level 4 Missions especially in  **The Blockade** and other rather **damage heavy and ECM rich missions**? And can I run those missions in an acceptable time frame?

Looks fine in EFT, but EFT Warriors are mostly those that lose their ships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't talk for the Proteus directly, but the Loki has been my first real missioning ship for level 4 missions and I'd say what I've learnt also applies to the other Strategic Cruisers. The Proteus might be a bit weaker damage wise in comparison to the others, but it's not too far off.

- Many level 4 missions can be completed in a Strategic Cruisers.
- There are several missions that will simply deal too heavy damage, even to a small ship such as a Strategic Cruisers (Angel Extravaganza bonus room; several Rogue Drone missions, if you trigger waves too early, etc.).
- Webbing is your death: Missions with heavy webbing (either elite frigates or those pesky 90% Spider Drones) will kill you, as speed/transversal is a significant part of your tank.
- A properly fitted Battleship will be far more effective (considering damage, tank and completion time), especially considering the budget you'll need to fit a Strategic Cruiser. It might be a bit more boring, but it's also a lot easier to pull off with less risk involved.
- A T3 is perfectly fine, if you're flying with others (e.g. corp mates).

A conclusion? Personal choice. If you're flying level 4 missions, because you're looking for a challenge or just for fun, go with the T3 (but be careful). If you want to collect LP and make money, consider using a Battleship.

Side note: If you insist on making your money with a Tech 3, I'd suggest you try Incursions. Most Strategic Cruisers are a very welcome addition, when properly fit, and you'll face less dangers and issues with Logistics, other ships, etc. being around.

Comment: Sound advice, and good point to try Incursions.

Comment: Sounds good, even though I hate the answer hehe. I would really like to fly one of those T3, but seems to be a bad idea.

Comment: Want to mission in a T3? Fit for a missile Tengu. Yes, i did read your comment below, saying you didn't wanted to learn missiles skills, but the Tengu is ATM the best strategic cruiser, even after the missile nerf... (I run L4 missions in SC, and i run epic arc L4 missions in dual SC with a friend... But we're using missiles tengus. It would'nt work in a proteus.)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest switching the CPU Efficiency Gate to a Dissolution Sequencer (because you don't need the extra CPU, and the DS will help with Sensor Strength vs ECM ). You may want to look into switching the rails for blasters (because you are much faster than anything in the mission), for the added DPS and close range damage reduction.

I'm not 100% that the prot is viable as a L4 mission ship, but this is how I'd do it:

```
[Proteus, missions] 
Proteus Defensive - Nanobot Injector 
Proteus Electronics - Dissolution Sequencer 
Proteus Engineering - Capacitor Regeneration Matrix 
Proteus Offensive - Hybrid Propulsion Armature
Proteus Propulsion - Localized Injectors

5x Heavy Neutron Blaster II (Federation Navy Antimatter Charge M)

10MN Afterburner II 
2x Stasis Webifier II 
Cap Recharger II

Medium Armor Repairer II 
Armor Kinetic Hardener II 
2x Armor Thermic Hardener II 
2x Magnetic Field Stabilizer II 
Energized Adaptive Nano Membrane II

Medium Hybrid Collision Accelerator I 
Medium Hybrid Burst Aerator I

5x Hobgoblin II 5x Hammerhead II
```

All skills L5, clean head:

```
[Statistics]
Effective HP: 84,327 (Eve: 11,986)
Tank Ability: 855.50 DPS
Damage Profile - Serpentis (EM: 0.00%, Ex: 0.00%, Ki: 37.85%, Th: 62.15%)
Shield Resists - EM: 0.00%, Ex: 50.00%, Ki: 85.00%, Th: 60.00%
Armor Resists - EM: 62.50%, Ex: 32.50%, Ki: 94.28%, Th: 93.45%
Capacitor (Stable at 31.26%)
Volley Damage: 2,220.30
DPS: 728.30
```

Comment: As stated, I am not looking for pure EFT Warriors and All V is an Illusion anyway. I am looking for real experience. Did you fly this ship in missions?

Comment: @user28015 Good god no. I fly Tengu/Drake for missions. I don't think anyone in their right mind would fly a Proteus for missions; If you're stuck on Gallente just use a Dominix instead if you're looking for a drone boat - less train time, better tank, less cost. For Hybrids look to the Megathron or Hyperion.

Comment: Giving a fit for a ship you don't and won't fly isn't that helpful

Comment: @APaleShadow Actually, I would fly this fit if I had to. I don't think the ship is fit to mission in. I expressed this plainly. I offered him alternatives based on my experience. Is it exactly what the question was looking for? No. Is it within the realm of the question? Yes.